# make remote branch 5 commits back

Tags: git, github

I have committed and pushed the branch. Now I decided to revert the last two commit, I know I can do `git reset --hard HEAD~2`, and I just did it. Now in my local branch, the commits are two steps back. But how can I push this to remote branch? I mean how can I make remote branch also be 2 commits back?

The reason why I ask is , after I did above reverting locally, I changed code & committed. When I push to remote repo, I got reject error:

```
Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
```

**==== UPDATE ====**

I tried @Tim Biegeleisen's answer, `git revert --no-commit HEAD~5..` but get error :

```
error: commit d7f37d67f8dbdaecc534c06316b7417657e527 is a merge but no -m option was given. fatal: revert failed
```

And the remote branch shows the latest commit is a "Merge branch 'foo' of ..."

Comment: Are you alone on this repo? Or sharing it with anyone?

Comment: `git push` doesn't work?

Comment: @niCkcAMel it should *not* unless OP forces it, since history has been rewritten.

Comment: @RomainValeri makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your branch is public and shared, you probably should *not* do a hard reset to actually remove the top 2 commits.  Instead, use `git revert`:

```
git revert master~2..master
```

or maybe

```
git revert --no-commit HEAD~2..
```

This will add a new commit on top of the `HEAD` of your `master` branch, which will functionally undo the current top 2 commits.  Note that those commits will still be there, which means that anyone who pulls will just get a new commit coming in.

**Edit:**

Based on your comment and error message, it appears that one of the two commits is a merge commit.  This means that you will need to tell Git which of the two parents to follow when doing the revert.  I don't know of a way to do this in a single command with a range of commits, but we can try doing two separate reverts.  Assuming the HEAD points to the merge commit:

```
git revert -m 1 abc123    # or use -m 2 to follow the other parent
```

Here `abc123` is the SHA-1 hash of the HEAD commit, which you may find by using `git log`.  Then, do a second revert for the second commit:

```
git revert xyz345
```

Comment: Tried the 2nd command, now I get `error: commit d7f37d67f8dbdaecc534c06316b7417657e527 is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: revert failed
`

Comment: @Leem It looks like you have one or more merge commits in there.  This complicates things, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: what is xyz345 in your example? Say, I now need to revert 5 commits back. The top commit is the merge one

Comment: Then revert the merge commit followed by `git revert master~6..master~2`

Comment: I git revert one by one the commits now with command `git revert <hash>`, but there is no new commit added on top of the head, that I have nothing to push to remote. The question still valid that how can I update the remote branch to be the same as reverted local branch.

Comment: I don't know what you did, but if there are no revert commits showing up, then you did something wrong.

Comment: It turns out even though there isn't new commit generated by those revertings, but after I git push origin my-branch-name, it does update the remote branch to the reverted version.

Comment: I actually did exactly what your answer suggested. For other people encounter the same problem: this answer solves the problem but there is no revert commits showing up(at least for me).  I just push the branch after reverting, it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you do an ordinary `git push` it will probably tell you you're behind and that you need to sync, but if you do a `git push --force` it will update the remote branch to the previous commit.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend doing a reset.

The safest way is doing a revert, like this:

```
git revert enter-your-commit-id-here
```

And then safely pushing to the remote.

Comment: Would it revert until commit id or would it revert the commit of the commit id in the command?

Comment: @Leem This use would only revert 1 commit, so it would have to be run 2 times. For the Question is better to use Tim answer, this one applies for a more generic case

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. Could you please take a look ?

Comment: Sure, but what about `git revert master~2..master` ?

Comment: Should I change `master` to the branch name I am using? and if I want to revert 5 steps, should I use 5 instead of 2?

Comment: Yes, checked and tried, but there is no new commit generated by git for those reverts that I still don't get how to update the remote branch to be the same as local reverted version.